# Closing a dropdown while hovering an image

Tags: jquery

I'm kinda noob on jquery.

How can I close a dropdown while hovering an image during jqzoom?

```
jQuery(".zoomimage").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(this).focus();
});
```

I had this but it is having problem with chrome when jqzoom is loading and it is really slow.

Comment: closing or choosing  ??  do you want to select value in dropdown ? why you trying focus ?

Comment: closing a dropdown.. im not selecting a value.. im focusing on the image so the dropdown will close but then on chrome it is not working properly

Comment: what that mean ?  hide  or unslect the value

Comment: just unselecting the dropdown.. more on accessibility issues

Comment: it is like clicking outside the dropdown..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ..am not sure it work or not.!

```
jQuery(".zoomimage").mouseenter(function(){
 $('#selectboxid').focus();
});
```

You can try setting the selected value of select box to blank or zero which ever is the dfault one

```
$("#selectBox").val(" ");
```